Depended dropdown with extra nested if statement
I have the following code, that works, for a depended dropdown menu.
Right now it does: IF column 5 <> "", then put depended dropdown of that name in column 6.
And if column 6 <> "", then put depended dropdown of that name in column 2.
This works perfectly but I need one extra step. I want that IF column 5 == "KITS" (this specific string text), then go straight to putting depended dropdown of that name in column 2 and skip the column6 step.
What I have now:
function depDrop_(range, sourceRange) {
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(sourceRange, true).build();
    range.setDataValidation(rule);
}

function onEdit () {
    var aCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
    var aColumn = aCell.getColumn();

    if (aColumn == 5 && SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()) {
        var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(aCell.getRow(), aColumn + 1);
        var sourceRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(aCell.getValue());
        depDrop_(range, sourceRange);
    }
    else if (aColumn == 6 && SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()) {
        var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(aCell.getRow(), aColumn - 4);
        var sourceRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(aCell.getValue());
        depDrop_(range, sourceRange);
    }
}

And I need help with this:
function depDrop_(range, sourceRange) {
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(sourceRange, true).build();
    range.setDataValidation(rule);
}

function onEdit () {
    var aCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
    var aColumn = aCell.getColumn();
    // if (aColumn == 5 && aColumn == "KITS" && SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()){
    var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(aCell.getRow(), aColumn - 3);
    var sourceRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(aCell.getValue());
    depDrop_(range, sourceRange);
}
else if (aColumn == 5 && SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()) {
    var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(aCell.getRow(), aColumn + 1);
    var sourceRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(aCell.getValue());
    depDrop_(range, sourceRange);
}
else if (aColumn == 6 && SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()) {
    var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(aCell.getRow(), aColumn - 4);
    var sourceRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(aCell.getValue());
    depDrop_(range, sourceRange);
}
}

I first tried it as stated above, that didn't work. And I tried putting "KITS" in a nested IF but also couldn't get that to work.

Typoalert: it's a column - not a "colomn" ("u" after the "l" - not "o") ...
